# web scraping with python. can't access td element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape from this address: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/

It is a page of game scores for American Football. I want to get the date, winner, and loser of each game. I have no problem accessing the date, however can not figure out how to isolate and grab the team names for the winners and losers.
What I have so far...

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


#assigning url
my_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

games = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"game_summary expanded nohover"})


for game in games:
    date_block = game.findAll("tr",{"class":"date"})
    date_val = date_block[0].text
    winner_block = game.findAll("tr",{"class":"winner"})
    #here I need a line that returns the game winner, e.g. "Philadelphia Eagles"
    loser = game.findAll("tr",{"class":"loser"})
```

And here is the relevant html...

```
<div class="game_summary expanded nohover">
<table class="teams">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="date">
            <td colspan="3">Sep 6, 2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="loser">
            <td><a href="/teams/atl/2018.htm">Atlanta Falcons</a></td>
            <td class="right">12</td>
            <td class="right gamelink">
                <a href="/boxscores/201809060phi.htm">Final</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="winner">
            <td><a href="/teams/phi/2018.htm">Philadelphia Eagles</a></td>
            <td class="right">18</td>
            <td class="right">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="stats">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>PassYds</strong></td>
            <td><a href="/players/R/RyanMa00.htm" title="Matt Ryan">Ryan</a>-ATL</td>
            <td class="right">251</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>RushYds</strong></td>
            <td><a href="/players/A/AjayJa00.htm" title="Jay Ajayi">Ajayi</a>-PHI</td>
            <td class="right">62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>RecYds</strong></td>
            <td><a href="/players/J/JoneJu02.htm" title="Julio Jones">Jones</a>-ATL</td>
            <td class="right">169</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I get an error saying the ResultSet object has no attribute "td". Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the tie game, I think that is what is causing your error as there is no winner in that case thus you won't find a row with the winner class. The below code outputs the date and winner.

```
for game in games:
    date_block = game.find('tr',{'class':'date'})
    date_val = date_block.text
    winner_block = game.find('tr',{'class':'winner'})
    if winner_block:
        winner = winner_block.find('a').text
        print(date_val)
        print(winner)
    loser = game.findAll('tr',{'class':'loser'})
```

Output:

```
Sep 6, 2018
Philadelphia Eagles
Sep 9, 2018
New England Patriots
Sep 9, 2018
Tampa Bay Buccaneers
Sep 9, 2018
Minnesota Vikings
Sep 9, 2018
Miami Dolphins
Sep 9, 2018
Cincinnati Bengals
Sep 9, 2018
Baltimore Ravens
Sep 9, 2018
Jacksonville Jaguars
Sep 9, 2018
Kansas City Chiefs
Sep 9, 2018
Denver Broncos
Sep 9, 2018
Washington Redskins
Sep 9, 2018
Carolina Panthers
Sep 9, 2018
Green Bay Packers
Sep 10, 2018
New York Jets
Sep 10, 2018
Los Angeles Rams
```

Comment: Haha glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty much correct.

```
html = ''' ... '''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')  # or 'html.parser' either way
print([elem.text for elem in soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'loser'})])
['\nAtlanta Falcons\n12\n\nFinal\n\n']`
```

What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Turns out it was the one tie game that messing it up. there wasn't a "winner" and "loser: class for that of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can anchor your search from the `"game_summaries"` `div`:

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/').text, 'html.parser')
def get_data(_soup_obj, _headers):
  _d = [(lambda x:[c.text for c in x.find_all('td')] if x is not None else [])(_soup_obj.find(a, {'class':b})) for a, b in _headers]
  if all(_d):
    [date], [t1, val, _], [t2, val2, _] = _d
    return {'date':date, 'winner':{'team':t1, 'score':int(val)}, 'loser':{'team':t2, 'score':int(val2)}}
  return {}

headers = [['tr', 'date'], ['tr', 'winner'], ['tr', 'loser']]
games = [get_data(i, headers) for i in d.find('div', {'class':'game_summaries'}).find_all('div', {'class':'game_summary'})]
print(json.dumps(games, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "date": "Sep 6, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Philadelphia Eagles",
        "score": 18
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Atlanta Falcons",
        "score": 12
    }
 },
  {
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "New England Patriots",
        "score": 27
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Houston Texans",
        "score": 20
    }
 },
 {
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
        "score": 48
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "New Orleans Saints",
        "score": 40
    }
 },
 {
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Minnesota Vikings",
        "score": 24
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "San Francisco 49ers",
        "score": 16
    }
 },
 {
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Miami Dolphins",
        "score": 27
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Tennessee Titans",
        "score": 20
    }
},
{
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Cincinnati Bengals",
        "score": 34
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Indianapolis Colts",
        "score": 23
    }
},
{},
{
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Baltimore Ravens",
        "score": 47
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Buffalo Bills",
        "score": 3
    }
},
{
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Jacksonville Jaguars",
        "score": 20
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "New York Giants",
        "score": 15
    }
},
{
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Kansas City Chiefs",
        "score": 38
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Los Angeles Chargers",
        "score": 28
    }
},
{
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Denver Broncos",
        "score": 27
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Seattle Seahawks",
        "score": 24
    }
},
{
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Washington Redskins",
        "score": 24
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Arizona Cardinals",
        "score": 6
    }
},
{
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Carolina Panthers",
        "score": 16
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Dallas Cowboys",
        "score": 8
    }
},
{
    "date": "Sep 9, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Green Bay Packers",
        "score": 24
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Chicago Bears",
        "score": 23
    }
},
{
    "date": "Sep 10, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "New York Jets",
        "score": 48
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Detroit Lions",
        "score": 17
    }
},
{
    "date": "Sep 10, 2018",
    "winner": {
        "team": "Los Angeles Rams",
        "score": 33
    },
    "loser": {
        "team": "Oakland Raiders",
        "score": 13
     }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into the issue that there was a tie this week. There's no winner TD in the Pittsburgh/Cleveland game. Running this should output all the games including the tie game:

```
for game in games:
    date_block = game.findAll("tr",{"class":"date"})
    date_val = date_block[0].text
    print "Game Date: %s" % (date_val)
    #Test if a winner is defined
    if game.find("tr",{"class":"winner"}) is not None:        


        winner_block = game.findAll("tr",{"class":"winner"})
        #Get the winner from the first TD and print text only
        winner = winner_block[0].findAll("td")
        print "Winner: %s" % (winner[0].get_text())

        loser_block = game.findAll("tr",{"class":"loser"})
        #Get the loser from the first TD and print text only
        loser = loser_block[0].findAll("td")
        print "Loser: %s" % (loser[0].get_text())
    else:
        #If no winner is listed, it must be a tie. Get both teams and print them.
        print "Its a tie!"
        draw_block  = game.findAll("tr",{"class":"draw"})
        for team in draw_block:
            print "Draw : %s"   % (team.findAll("td")[0].get_text())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was indeed the issue.